# FOSRESTBundle: how to alter serializer metadatadirs at controller level

Tags: serialization, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

How can I specify a metadata dir for the serializer used by FOSRestBundle, at controller level?

I can't set it up in `config.yml` because in my case it depends on the request's route.

I've seen in [JMSSerializer doc](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/configuration#configuring-metadata-locations) that I could use the following code

```
$serializer = JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()
    ->addMetadataDir($someDir)
    ->build();
```

But how to apply it to an already instanciated serializer (or how to replace it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible.

Directories are set to metadata drivers when calling [`build()` in `SerializerBuilder.php`](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/src/JMS/Serializer/SerializerBuilder.php#L350).

Even though [you can access the metadata factory](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/src/JMS/Serializer/Serializer.php#L195) used by the `Serializer` it probably won't help you because the factory has nothing to do with cache directories. Only drivers work with directories.

So the only option for you is probably to create a new instance of `Serializer` and use that instead of the one from DI.

Edit: Creating a new `Serializer` works the same way as in your question. Then your DI container should be an instance of [Container](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.html) that has method `set()` which lets you override any registered service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you add to your answer how I could *"create a new instance of Serializer and use that instead of the one from DI"* with FOSRestBundle?

Comment: OK, I still don't see how I could apply this to FOSRestBundle, but I'll accept your answer anyway. Thanks.